# Generating a random salt to be used across devices

Tags: php, android

I am writing an app that use an API that returns results in json from an app that will be running on Android and iPhone. I want to generate an API key but this is easily detected giving anyone access to the API.

What I propose to do is to use a random salt based on a phrase and the date and hour of the day. However, if I generate a salt based on the hour it will fail if I send a request at 1 second to 9 and the server is actually at 10 by the time it gets the request. I could test for this scenario and decrease the hour and retest.

Does anyone have any ideas for a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a shorter time span, like 10 minutes.  Check against the 10's.  So, if it is `2:03`, valid hashes would be `2:00`, `1:50`, and `2:10`

Comment: Thanks for that. I was hoping for a better solution than using the time. I did wonder if there was anything I could get off the phone to generate the salt. Maybe the ip address and some other data.